# Custom HTML tag: good or bad practise?

Tags: html, tags, web

Recently, I have been charged to conceive a web application. I am quite familiar with the "classical", old way to achieve it using HTML, CSS and JavaScript. But now, I would like to do something nicer.

I moved from JavaScript to TypeScript, from plain CSS to frameworks such as Bootstrap. And, I would like to do something with the HTML. I found that something that bothers me with HTML is the usage of "div" for nearly everything.

However, I did not found any standard, widely compatible way to solve this problem. If I relax the hypothesis to use only standard methods, maybe, using custom HTML tags could add some more expressiveness to my app.

Do someone have experience with it? Is it a bad idea? Is there famous websites that use this method? Is there different support depending on the navigator? Is there important points I need to take care of?

Could someone give me a argumented answer to help me to decide what to do? 
Personnally, I find this kind of code much clearer that equivalent standard HTML:

```
<app-article-list>
    <app-article> 
        <article-title>Hello</article-title>
        <article-date>10/04/1995</article-date>
        <article-body>I am the body of the article</article-body>
    </app-article>
<app-article-list>
```

Thank you very much

Comment: How do you plan on creating custom HTML tags?

Comment: Just by using undefined tags (like in the example), maybe by cleaning their placement properties with CSS. I don't plan to use the "custom element" HTML 5 system because it is not much supported yet.